# Reading a file path in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new at VBA and have tried searching the questions for this but with no luck. I have a workbook that lists the file path in A1, workbook name in B1, and tab names in C1 & D1. I am try to write a macro that will open a file from cell A1, then set the workbook it just opened from the original B1, and set the worksheet names in C1 & D1. Then go one row below and loop the process. I think I managed to work through most of it except defining the variable paths/workbooks/sheets. Below is what I have come up with so far. Would anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

```
Dim Macro As Workbook
Set Macro = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb")
Workbooks.Open Range("A1")
Dim WBRange As Range
WBRange = Macro.Range("B1").Value
Dim ParRange As Range
Set ParRange = Macro.Range("C1").Value
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
Set CurrentWB = WBRange
Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
Set CurrentWS = ParRange
```

Comment: Workbooks contain worksheets which contain cells. Workbooks do not contain cells.

Comment: does that code work? setting a workbook to a value of a cell? and the same with wbRange?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav - `Workbooks.Open Range("A1")` is syntactically correct (would open the workbook whose name was specified in cell A1 of the active sheet) but would need to be something like `Workbooks.Open Range("A1") & Range("B1")` based on what is written in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. It looks like you may be a bit confused about using ranges for variables. See my code below:

```
' Use a better name than this for your variable
Dim Macro As Workbook
Set Macro = Workbooks("Macros.xlsb")

Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
' Notice that I fully qualify my range reference here, and then specifically retrieve the value from the cell.
Set NewWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheetname").Range("A1").Value)

' You dont retrieve the value here. You also don't specify the workbook/sheet the range is in.
' Workbooks.Open Range("A1")

Dim WBRange As Range
' You always have to use set when assigning a value to an object
' This was a mistake as well.
' Set WBRange = Macro.Range("B1").Value
Set WBRange = Macro.Range("B1")

Dim ParRange As Range
' This was my mistake and causes an error. See the fix below:
' Set ParRange = Macro.Range("C1").Value
Set ParRange = Macro.Range("C1")

Dim CurrentWB As Workbook
' Set CurrentWB = WBRange
' I think you mean this:
Set CurrentWB = Workbooks(WBRange.Value)

Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet
'Set CurrentWS = ParRange
' Use this instead
Set CurrentWS = CurrentWB.Sheets(ParRange.Value)
```

First, when using ranges it is best to always qualify their path. So first, the workbook, then the worksheet. You can also use a worksheet variable that has been set.

Next, if you are retrieving a value from a range you must use `Range.Value`. While the default member of Range is Value, you will run into cases where the wrong member is retrieved (for example you could retrieve the Range itself). Also, you can't just set a worksheet equal to a name of a worksheet by referring to that name without a qualifier. You can use the name as an indexer though. In my code above, I use the name of the workbook to find it within the Workbooks collection. Same for the worksheet.

I hope this helps clarify!

Comment: I have a lot to learn! When I update the code to what you provided, I get an error at:
    Set ParRange = Macro.Range("C1").Value with the error

Comment: Oh, my stupid mistake. Remove the ".Value". In this case, we want the cell itself so we shouldnt try to retrieve on if it's members using a "." , If we do just `Set ParRange = Macro.Range("C1")` we will directly assign ParRange to point to the cell itself, and not its contents. Updated my code to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, I realized you can't edit a comment after 5 minutes. But I still get the error "Object doesn't support this property or method (Error 438)" when I remove the ".Value".(In both the ParRange and the WBRange ) As a note, in the Macro (I will use a more appropriate name ) workbook Cell A1 has the file path(C:\FolderFileName.xlsx), in cell B1 the file name(FileName.xlsx), and C1 the tab name. My understanding of the Range function is that it just stores the value. I tried removing the ".xlsx" part in B1 but doesn't change anything.

Comment: I think I figured it out.

 `Dim WBRange As Variant`
  `Set WBRange = Macro.Sheets("Altas Par Recs").Range("B1")` 

is what I ended up using and it seems to work

Comment: @Epoch Don't use a Variant to overcome an obstacle. It will ultimately lead to buggy code. It is much better to work through the problem and figure out what is going on. Also, the 'Range' object stores the 'Range' itself. So in the case of `Range("C1")` we aren't storing the contents of the cell, but the cell itself. You shouldnt be getting an error when doing something like `Set ParRange = Macro.Range("C1")`. There is likely something else happening. Be sure to step through your code and ensure that Macro is set properly, and that there are no typos.

Comment: To elaborate on Variants, the issue is that they don't have a specific 'Type'. This can be an issue because we don't get any compile-time error checking (meaning we don't get warnings when we hit the Run button) and they can change their type at will. Consider something like this `Dim test as Variant; test = 10; Debug.Print test.value`. This code will compile just fine despite the fact that it will likely default to a 'Type' of 'Integer' when it is given the value of 10, and will then run into the 438 error from above since `.Value` is not a member of 'Integer'.